# how load local html on air sdk harman

Tags: android, actionscript-3, sdk, air, harman

how load local html on air sdk harman, i use StageWebView on AS3, if i run on its normal view, but if i make apk and instal on android phone, its error. Application cannot showing local html. I use air SDK harman 33.1.1.554.

this my code :

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("html");
var destinasi:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
file.copyTo(destinasi, true);
var hasil:String = "file://" + destinasi.resolvePath("index.html").nativePath;
isiMenu4.loadURL(hasil);
```

is there issue about security on air sdk by harman? how to skip that?

Comment: Just a guess, but try this: **var hasil:String = destinasi.resolvePath("index.html").url;** instead of the line you have there.

Comment: we try it but not showing result. we get error
`Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Load error.`

Comment: Well, you should probably handle it and get more details from the error, right?

Comment: thanks for your answer, this issue just view on device when instal apk. On virtual, my codes runs normal when compile, no issue. Maybe Android canmot showing know all html loader.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue where you don't have Android permission to write to local storage.

Try creating the directory first and see if that throws any errors.

```
_file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("html");
                    
trace("html.url", _file.url);
trace("html.nativePath", _file.nativePath);
                    
if (!_file.exists) {
_file.createDirectory();
//make storage directory non backupable
_file.preventBackup = true;
}
```

Comment: I believe it to be incorrect. The **File.applicationStorageDirectory** is a sacred folder where the app has full R/W permission even without asking for it explicitly. I checked that back on Android 6 and AIR 24 (but even on Windows it is somewhere under C:\\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\YourAppID and on Linux it has its place as well), when more strict permission rules were introduced, and I doubt anything has changed in this regard since then.